# Should I superglue a corner of my laptop case back together? If so how?

Tags: laptop, laptop-repair, case

I have a corner of a Lenovo Ideapad 510 that pops open all the time (at the hinge), and it's getting annoying, so I was wondering if it would be a good idea from a laptop tech perspective to just superglue the laptop corner shut.

Comment: Superglue on the plastic won't cause any noticeable issue, unless it is made of something that reacts badly to superglue, however if it's popping open near a hinge, it's likely there's something forcing it open (bad design?) and so it won't be a lasting fix.

Comment: If gluing works, your laptop will no longer be serviceable.  Better to figure out why it's popping open and fix the actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a missing screw? If so, insert a compatible screw (correct size and threading). If not, assuming you never want to separate them again, an adhesive should work; I suggest using only a small amount of a gel formulation.

*EDIT:* Based on the comment below, the palm rest should be replaced; [page 39 of this PDF](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/ideapad_510-15isk_510-15ikb_hmm_201604.pdf) is how you do it. Good luck figuring out which one you need, though (page 61, "upper case"); you should bring it in to a Lenovo authorized service center.

Comment: I never opened the laptop, it's what the wrists rest on, and it's the clip

Comment: @acoder I edited my answer above to reflect your comment.